# Deleting Blank Pages in Word Doc with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to write a function to delete blank pages in a Word doc. Nothing gets deleted. I appreciate it if somebody can take a look.

```
Public Function DeleteBlankPages(wd As Word.Document, wdApp As Word.Application)  
    Dim par As Paragraph
    For Each par In wd.Paragraphs
        If IsEmpty(par.Range.Text) Then
            par.Range.Select
            wdApp.Selection.Delete
        End If
    Next par       
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up the definition of `IsEmpty` in the VBA language reference. It doesn't do what you imagine.

The correct way to find out if there is textual content is to check the number of characters. In VBA, this is typically done with the function `Len` (=length). You'd think that it the comparision should be to 0 (zero), but that's not the case for a paragraph, because a Word paragraph *always* contains it's paragraph mark (ANSI 13).

Also, no need to *select* the paragraph or range in order to delete it, just use the `Delete`method directly on the `par.Range`. (Which means you also don't need to pass a `Word.Application` object.

Also note that your code doesn't do anything to pages, only to paragraphs... It *could* deleted empty pages, depending on how things are formatted, but it might be wise to rename the Function and comment how it's supposed to work.

So more like this:

```
Public Function DeleteBlankPages(wd As Word.Document)  
    Dim par As Paragraph
    For Each par In wd.Paragraphs
        If Len(par.Range.Text) <= 1 Then
            par.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next par       
End Function
```

Comment: This does not reply to the question that is "How to delete empty pages ?", as your code deletes empty paragraphs, regardless the rest of the page is empty or not

Comment: @SunWukong The original Q revolves around why its code does not work, it does not ask how to delete empty pages, although I agree the subject line does *imply* this is what the question would be about. Fact is, there is no simple way to "loop" pages in a Word document, given the fluid layouting behavior of the application. It can be done, and I believe that's described in various places on the Internet, but a lot depends on the type of document involved and how the blank pages have been generated, to begin with (i.e. was Enter pressed, odes it come from style defs, or odd/even settings...)