# How do I delete a BLANK page in a word document using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Public Function DeleteBlankPages(wd As Word.Document)  
    Dim par As Paragraph
    For Each par In wd.Paragraphs
        If Len(par.Range.Text) <= 1 Then
            par.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next par       
End Function
```

I tried the above code segment but it doesn't delete the blank pages. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *but it won't work* - what about it doesn't work for your situation?

Comment: The blank page is still not deleted after running the codes

Comment: Do you have a hard page break?  All that code does is remove empty paragraphs.

Comment: I suggest viewing all the formatting and see what is going on. As @Comintern says, all this code does is delete empty paragraphs.

Comment: When i press (Crtl Shift 8), there is still 1 paragraph mark. The only way to delete it is via manual way by changing the paragraph mark to 01..

Comment: When you copied the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37230764/8112776) how did you implement it into your project?  Where did you place the function and how are you calling it?  Also, what do you mean "the only way to delete the paragraph mark is manually"? You didn't research far; there are several posts like [this one](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008699_Searching_for_Paragraph_Marks_and_Line_Breaks.html). A good way to troubleshoot is to **step through the code** with [F8] to see what's going on. Here's more on [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: Currently, i'm using this to delete the blank page. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-a-page-in-word-174fedd3-b4e5-42e4-a4d0-5e25127a1404#StepTab=FullPageTables

Comment: Is there any other VBA codes whereby I can delete the empty page?  :D

Comment: Turn on the display of non-printing characters in the Word UI: that's the ¶ button on the Home tab. Look at the "blank page". What do you see on it? Certainly, you see at least one ¶. What else? We have to know that in order to help you. Note that in the text of the Answer where you copied this code I say explicitly that this code does not delete "blank pages" - but it's the way the person asked the question - I just modified the code so that it worked to do what the person asking wanted. At the time, I didn't have enough "rep" to do any editing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, if you just want to delete the blank Paragrph we can just add the following code to your VBA project. And then run the **main** from the **Macros**:

```
Sub main()
Set wd = ActiveDocument
   Dim par As Paragraph
    For Each par In wd.Paragraphs
        If Len(par.Range.Text) <= 1 Then
            par.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next par
End Sub
```

If we want to delete the blank page:
1. If you know the page index, we can use the following code:

```
Set rgePages = Selection.Range
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=PageCount
    rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
    rgePages.Delete
```

2. If you don't know the page index of blank page, we need to loop the PageCollection and use Trim to handle the page text and then delete the blank page. (But it seems the Trim doesn't work well on the Range text in word)

Comment: That code won't delete empty pages, such as may exist as a result of Section breaks, manual page breaks, or following the last table in a document where the table ends at the bottom of the page; all your code does is delete empty paragraphs, which is not the OP's issue.